# Why does a Dropbox account option show up when I launch the Add Account screen targeting my app

Tags: android, dropbox

I want to launch the "Add an account" while targeting my app. This is done by putting EXTRA_AUTHORITIES into my intent. Here's the code (with the package name changed):

```
public static void launchAddAcountActivity(Context context) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT).putExtra(
            Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES,
            new String[] {
                    "com.myproject.providers.AlbumsContentProvider" }));
}
```

My app does show up as an account option, but so does Dropbox. Other third-part accounts are hidden properly; I don't see Twitter or Facebook or others. Does anyone else run into this issue when they have Dropbox installed on their device? Is there a workaround that doesn't involve launching my activity directly?

Comment: you can add ComponentName or package name to your intent to narrow it down